# read and open PDF in a new browser window with JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Java / JSF

Im trying to open PDF in ***a new browser window*** instead of download it but in every try the file is downloaded with success and it opens a new tab with the application only and not the pdf file.

```
<p:commandLink title="report" target="_blank"
    action="#{managedBean.generateReport('P',true)}"
    ajax="false" immediate="false" >
</p:commandLink>
```

**Managed bean** : generateReport calls downloadFile

The filePath parameter below = /temp/doc/abc.pdf (chmod 777)

```
public static void downloadFile(String filePath) throws IOException{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context  
                         .getExternalContext().getResponse();  
    File file = new File(filePath);  
    if (!file.exists()) {  
      response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);  
      return;  
     }  
    response.reset();  
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);  
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");  
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));  
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""  
           + file.getName() + "\"");  
    BufferedInputStream input = null;  
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;  

    try 
    {  
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file),  
                    DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);  
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(),  
                        DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];  
        int length;  
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);  
        }  
    } finally 
    {  
        input.close();  
        output.close();  
    }  
    context.responseComplete();
}
```

My Chromium plugin is enabled :

[image]

Comment: how about <h:commandLink onclick="window.open(...);">?

Comment: Have you tried `Content-Disposition:inline` instead?

Comment: tried ..:inline and did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about primefaces `media` :

From the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml) :

```
<p:media value="/resources/other/guide.pdf" width="100%" height="300px"/>
```

Also you can put this PDF viewer in a `p:dialog` [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml).

Comment: good idea, I implemented with p:media and composite dialog box. Remember that p:media does not work with @ViewScoped.

Comment: What if, client is generating reports at run-time and not saving it on file system

Answer (score 1):

It has to be set to the PDF content type ("application/pdf") if you want the browser to know it is a PDF.  You are setting it to "application/octet-stream".

Comment: Check the headers from the browser.  If the PDF plugin installed is not loading it because the browser does not know the file MIME type.  Also.  Are you putting a .PDF extension on the file name value?

Answer (score -4):

At this line

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""  + file.getName() + "\"");
```

replace with

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\""  + file.getName() + "\"");
```

remove ==> attachment;  then  Pdf will open in new tab

Comment: Why should the OP do that? Please explain your answer.

Comment: Did you do/try it yourself?